# When you are running an analysis with only an intercept, does it make sense to include random subject and item intercepts?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, random-variable, random-effects-model, intercept

Lets image a study where people get two shapes and are told to pick one. They each get 40 trials, each with a different shape/colour. There are 40 different pairs of shapes. There are 100 participants. The DV is how often they choose the left one. (This isn't my study, just an example.)

I want to know if they choose the left shape more often than chance. The intercept of a logistic regression model tells me this. If all I have in the model is the intercept, is it sensible to include a random subject and item intercept? I did out of habit, but now that I think of it, it seems to not make much sense. If it does make sense can you explain why?

Edit: Let me add that there is another analysis in which each person only received two trials. On this analysis, including a random subject intercept increases the intercept value by almost five times. I'm struggling to get my head around this. How can a random subject intercept lead to such a larger intercept? How does the model "know" what to do with that variance in subjects, whether it is genuine or not.

Edit: [Output for the models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxDty.jpg) in which participants only got two trials, one that included a random subject intercept and one that did not.

Edit: I still find it hard to really grasp how the inclusion of a subject intercept changes the actual estimate of the intercept to such an extent. As I understand it, the random intercept tells the model that some people tend to score really high, and some people tend to score really low, and it models the variance in this difference. **But what sort of information in that variance could "tell" the model that the overall intercept should be higher?** I can imagine how that variance in subjects' intercepts would alter the p-value; but I don't totally understand it changing the intercept itself.

Comment: If you have repeated measures then you have to account for that. Random intercepts are a good way to do that.

Comment: Please can you include the output from the models where you noticed a large change in the intercept.

Comment: Hi @RobertLong just added the output.

Comment: The reason I'm very hesitant in the latter case is that there are only two observations per person. @RobertLong

Comment: For future reference, you can post the text output into your question, and delimit it with 3 backticks (```)  and the start and end, and the system will format it nicely. This way people will be able to copy/paste text directly. As for the models, the glmm seems good to me. It's not the number of obs per group (2) that's a limiting factor, it's the number of groups (95 which is obviously OK). It's normal for the logistic glm intercept to be baised when the random structure is mis-specified (absent altogether in this case). I could probably create a simple simulation to show this if you like ?

Comment: Nice question btw (+1)

Comment: Hi @RobertLong thanks for the answer! I'm still having some trouble grasping why the intercept would go up. See my edit.